# JUnit 5 @Theory and @DataPoint

Tags: junit5

I'm a bit of a newbie trying to learn JUnit and I'm working off material that I'm pretty sure is geared to teaching JUnit 4, but I'm trying to work in JUnit 5. And it's giving me an exercise to create a test with the @Theory and @DataPoints / @DataPoint.

Do these work in JUnit 5? And if so, can someone give a good overview or resource on how to use them? If not, what's the best way to recreate the functionality that these would give?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In JUnit 5 theories are called ParameterizedTest and DataPoints are given by means of a ValueSource

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(doubles = {Double.MIN_VALUE, -4.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY})
public void floorTest(double n) {
    assertEquals( (int)n, Math.floor( n ), 0 );
}
```